# For loop with steps other than 1

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to do a For loop with a jump 2*Pi instead of 1.

```
For[j = 0, j <= nmax, (incr = 2 Pi), ...]
```

Actually what I want to do is `j = n 2 Pi`, where `n` takes values from 0 to `n-1`, so the iteration stops at `nmax = (n - 1) 2 Pi`.

I know this is a pretty trivial question, but I have not found anything equivalent in the "Documentation center".

Comment: Please use [these tools](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to format your question.

Comment: You posted questions about looping before. Loops are discouraged in Mathematica. Please have a look at this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193

Comment: Arguably this is too trivial to feature in the documentation, although perhaps not since really the only reasonable use of `For` in *Mathematica* is for iterations having a very complicated structure that cannot easily be expressed otherwise (which isn't the case here, incidentally). Anyway, you can write whatever you want as the increment. In this case just put `j += 2 Pi`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the iterators in Mathematica work pretty much the same way.

```
(i, a, b, c}
```

means the variable is $i$, the starting value is $a$, the ending value is $b$ and the interval is $c$. So in your case,

```
 {j, 0, nmax, 2 Pi}
```

would do it. Honestly though, you should be able to program whatever it is you are doing without the `For` loop at all. For instance:

```
 Table[i, {i, 1.1, 2.3, Pi/10}]
```

gives you the values, $i$ in the specified range, and you can of course take any function of them using a construct like

```
 Table[f[i], {i, 1.1, 2.3, Pi/10}]
```

which applies the function `f` to the $i$. Somewhat more concise is

```
 Range[1.1, 2.3, Pi/10]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to get it on the record, the strict answer to your question is

```
With[{n =. ..}, For[j = 0, j <= (n - 1) 2 Pi, j += 2 Pi, ...]]
```

For example,

```
With[{n = 3}, For[j = 0, j <= (n - 1) 2 Pi, j += 2 Pi, Print[j]]]
```

produces

> 0
>   2 π
>   4 π

Not very different from what you would do in C.